# Defining Explicit Returns for AWS Boto3 Types

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, types, boto3

How can I replace `object` with the correct return type of `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance`? It's for intellisense purposes.

```
# Note: self._resource -> boto3.resource(...)

def instance(self, instance_id: str) -> object:
    """
    Gets EC2 instance based on Instance ID.
    :param instance_id: AWS EC2 Instance ID
    """
    instance = self._resource.Instance(instance_id)
    return instance
```

According to `type(ec2.instance('i-123456'))` (`ec2` in this example is the instance of the class which contains the `instance()` method), it returns `<class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance'>`. However, boto3 uses a factory pattern to return an instance of `Instance` class; which is hiding the location of the definition for the `Instance` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You specify an rtype in your docstring when you want to specify the return type](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/docstring_python.html).  Most IDEs will be smart enough to pick up on that.

```
    def instance(self, instance_id: str):
        """
        Gets EC2 instance based on Instance ID.
        :param instance_id: AWS EC2 Instance ID
        :rtype: boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance
        """
        instance = self._resource.Instance(instance_id)
        return instance
```

If you want to use python type hinting because you want to ensure some additional safety, you might want to use a TypeVar:

```
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T', bound='boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance')
```